How to convert string to wstring?
I know C++ has converter. But to know how memory is working i should know why i can not do that:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char* text = "hello";
    std::wstring* wtext = malloc(5);
    strcpy(wtext, text);
    std::wcout << wtext << std::endl;
    free(wtext);
    return 0;
}

"text" is pointer of "hello" 
"wtext" is pointer of memory which contains free 5 bytes 
function "strcpy" copies memory from pointer "text" to pointer "wtext" 
"std::wcout" is printing out this all 
"free" cleans old memory of pointer "wtext" \
If all of this theory is right ,then it should be working, but it is not. 
Why can not i resize something and put it into this one?
so C++ compiler says i can not use "malloc" on "wtext" because it has not the same types of variable. However, professor says pointers can have any things in it, because it is pointers. They can point at numbers, text, e.t.c. I did not understand what had happened.

malloc(5) will allocate five bytes, not space for five "elements" of whatever kind. It can't really be used as you want it to, as it's an old C function which have no knowledge of elements (in either language) or C++ objects.

For a start, read the section in your C++ tutorial that explains when and how to use new. But, why do you think you need to dynamically allocate storage to begin with? And why does it have to be a std::wstring, which is itself capable of managing dynamic memory itself?

As for your problem of converting a narrow-character string to a wide-character string, see std::mbstowcs.

All in all, it seems you have used a really bad resource to learn C++, and you mix in unrelated and non-working C concepts. If you're serious about learning C++ then please invest in some good books. And if you want to use wide characters and strings, use them from the start and all throughout your code. Most attempts to mix will likely become a mess.

Before you go on, first learn a bit more standard C++. For strings in C++ use std::string, and std::wstring.  And you never should use std::string*. Have a look at learncpp.com, cppreference.com and the C++ core guidelines. Who is teaching you  C++?

There are multiple issues here. Regarding your professor's comment about pointers, consider pointers a category. A pointer to float and a pointer to int are both pointers. The principle and characteristics behind them are the same. However, they are different kinds of pointers and are not freely interchangeable. Just like a cat and an ox are both mammals and they have common characteristics, but you would not try to use a cat to pull a plow.

As mentioned, there is no need for malloc here.  Second, even if you used malloc, this: std::wstring* wtext = malloc(5);  is not valid C++.  The malloc function returns a void *, and you can't assign a void * to a std::wstring *.  You have to cast the return value of malloc to the correct pointer type.

Side note: wchar_t , std::wstring, std::wcout are useless on Linux and macOS. They are indeed useful on Windows, but now I recommend to use UTF-8 std::string everywhere, and for Windows, add a manifest file to the executable to enable UTF-8 code page (possible since 2019).

You should never allocate C++ objects with malloc (nor deallocate with free).
malloc is a legacy from C. It only allocates raw memory and does not call the proper constructor.
In C++ you should (in principle) use new to dynamically allocate an object and get a pointer to it (and delete to deallocate).
In practice there are rare cases where you actually need to use raw pointers with manual new/delete. Usually using a smart pointer will be better.
But in the case of wstring there's no reason to use any kind of pointer at all. Just use the object directly.
Also if you make text a char array, you can use std::begin and std::end to initialize the wstring:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char text[] = "hello";
    std::wstring wtext(std::begin(text), std::end(text));
    std::wcout << wtext << std::endl;
}

Output:
hello

Live demo.
Note:
Reading your question and code example, I assumed your source string contains only ascii characters.
If this is not the case, you cannot simply initialize wtext from text as shown above. Instead you will need to use some API to convert it, like std::wstring_convert, std::mbstowcs etc. These documentation links also show some usage examples.

Just note that creating a std::wstring from a std::string by copying the characters as-is, as this code is doing, will corrupt non-ASCII characters. You need an actual data conversion, like std::wstring_convert(), std::mbstowcs() or other equivalent Unicode API.

@RemyLebeau good point. Reading the question and the code I thought the OP needed a trivial copy-like operation. Added a note.

that wouldn't work with const char* though

#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Include <string> for std::wstring

int main() {
    const char* text = "hello";
    std::wstring wtext = std::wstring(text, text + strlen(text)); // Convert const char* to std::wstring

    std::wcout << wtext << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


This probably works fine if text only contains ASCII, but if it contains something UTF8 encoded, this method won't work.

Agreed. You need an actual data conversion, like std::wstring_convert(), std::mbstowcs() or other equivalent Unicode API.

it's unnecessary slow as you walking the string twice, one to count the characters and second time to copy them.

If you don't need to convert the string and just create wstring with the same but wide characters, then it's a one line of code:
std::wstring destination{std::from_range, "string"};

and for assignment you can also use destination.assign_range("string");
